# Can a smooth manifold be embedded into its tangent bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold, tangent-bundle

Given a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, one can always find an immersion into its tangent bundle $TM$ by looking at the zero-section, i.e. the map that sends $p\in M$ to $(p,0)\in TM$. One can see this is an immersion for example by writing everything in local coordinates and checking that this is locally an inclusion.

Can it be proved that this is also an embedding? (i.e. a homeomorphism onto its image). It seems intuitively clear to me that this should be true because "the tangent bundle has a copy of $M$ inside" but I can't find a way to prove or disprove it. Could you help me?

Comment: Locally an inclusion is not what you should have said. Why can’t you find a way to prove an embedding?  Say specifically what you need to prove and where you get stuck.

Comment: Actually, I think I've been studying too hard! Now that I wrote it in paper I think it is completely immediate.... the map is clearly injective and the inverse is the canonical projection which is continuous as it is differentiable... Sorry to waste everyone's time! I'll delete my question!

Comment: No, please do not delete your question

Comment: What you said in your comment above is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

(EDIT: This is false! leaving it up cause there's a useful comment.) Let $\phi: X \to Y$ be an injective map of topological spaces which you wish to check is a homeomorphism onto its image. **You can check this locally**: if $\{U_i\}$ is a cover of $X$ such that $\phi|_{U_i}$ is a homeomorphism onto its image for all $i$, then $\phi$ is a homeomorphism onto its image.

This fact works out great in your case, where $X$ is a manifold, since you can take $\{U_i\}$ to be a coordinate chart, and you are reduced to proving that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to its image in its (trivial) tangent bundle $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$, which is true.

Comment: This statement is not true. For example, consider $\phi\colon \mathbb R\to S^1\times S^1$ given by $\phi(t) = (e^{2\pi i t}, e^{2\pi i \alpha t})$, where $\alpha$ is an irrational number. Then each point of $\mathbb R$ has a neighborhood on which $\phi$ is a homeomorphism onto its image, but $\phi$ is not a homeomorphism onto its image. See Example 4.20 in my _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_ (2nd ed.).